# How to change include php changing with date?

Tags: php, include

I have an include php

```
<?php readfile("./mois/XX.php");?>
```

XX is month of the year

Example for the month of september i want this inlude :

```
<?php readfile("./month/9.php");?>
```

for october :

```
<?php readfile("./month/10.php");?>
```

....
XX change with month

Thanks for your help

Comment: Welcome to [so]! We will be glad to help if you get stuck on a specific programming problem, but we are not here to write code or design your system for you. You will need to at least make an attempt at solving your own issue. Please see [ask] a good question and [What topics can I ask about here?](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) After [doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592) if you have a problem you can post what you've tried with a clear explanation of what isn't working and providing a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try

```
<?php
$month = date("m");

readfile("./month/".$month.".php");
// here $month = 08 (current month of august)

// if you want single digit month then try
$monthonedigit = date("n");
readfile("./month/".$monthonedigit.".php");
// here $monthonedigit= 8 (current month of August)
?>
```

Also check for your typoerrors , if any

because you provided `mois` here

```
<?php readfile("./mois/XX.php");?>
```

And in example.. `month`

```
<?php readfile("./month/9.php");?>
```